# Make google packaged apps windows draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps

I have a Google Packaged apps. I have put `frame: 'none'` in my `manifest.json` file to remove the title bar. But now I am having a problem on how to make it draggable. From the documentation:

> -webkit-app-region CSS property can be used to apply draggability to the app's window. -webkit-app-region: drag can be used to mark regions
>   draggable. no-drag can be used to disable this style on nested
>   elements

But the problem is I don't know how to use it and where I should put it. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you show more codes?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way, I put that script in my html tag.

```
<body style="-webkit-app-region: drag;">
```

Then my window is now draggable, cheers!

Comment: I had to put it into the `<html>` tag for it to work.